how to generate traffic to increment FramesLostDueToIntMACXmitError
I am working to verify a network driver. As part of that I need to see if the following counters get incremented
# ethtool -S eth0 --groups eth-mac | grep FramesLost
FramesLostDueToIntMACXmitError
FramesLostDueToIntMACRcvError

Which tools can I use to get these to increment?
I tried iptables to add a rule and then send ping but it didn't cause any increase in these counters.

Welcome to the site. While editing your post to improve the presentation, I made the implicit assumption that you ran the command as root user. If that is not the case, please edit again to replace the # prompt with the usual $ indicating a non-root user.
